# create graph using custom xml on javascript

Tags: javascript, xml, mxgraph

I have a simple server - client architecture.
I would like to create mxgraph using custom xml on client side with javascript.
Here is the structure of my xml:

```
<mycustomroot>
<!-- some not mxgraph related tags -->
<some-custom-tag>
 ......
</some-custom-tag>

<!-- this is standard mxgraph model-->
<mxGraphModel>
  ......
</mxGraphModel>

<!-- this is standard mxgraph stylesheet-->
<mxStylesheet>
  .....
</mxStylesheet>
</mycustomroot>
```

My first question is:
How can I create from this xml a graph?
(I dont want to write custom parser, because everything in  is standards mxgraph.)
I would like to do something like:

dec.decode(node, graph.getModel());

(where the node is the mxgraphmodel tag in the xml.)

The second question is:
I would like to use icons, which are sent by the server as text based byte array.
In the mxConstants the STYLE_IMAGE description is not really useful.

Thanks your answers in advance!

Answer (score 0):

you just need to parse your file right?

```
parser = new DOMParser();
xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(text,"text/xml");
```

with text the xml you receive converted in string